# cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object when modifying a var inside a function

Tags: python

I keep getting a "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" whenever I try to change the value of Ap inside the function.
It works perfectly fine if I don't touch it.

```
def Apple_Spawner(Ap,Ax,Ay):

    if Ap==0:
        Color=255,0,0
        Ax,Ay = random.randint(1,50),random.randint(0,50)
        Ax,Ay = Ax*10+5, Ay*10+5

        while True:

            if Ax not in PosX and Ay not in PosY:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,Color,(Ax-5,Ay-5),(Ax+5,Ay-5))
                pygame.draw.line(screen,Color,(Ax-5,Ay+5),(Ax+5,Ay+5))
                pygame.draw.line(screen,Color,(Ax-5,Ay+5),(Ax-5,Ay-5))
                pygame.draw.line(screen,Color,(Ax+5,Ay+5),(Ax+5,Ay-5))

                break

            else:
                Ax,Ay = random.randint(1,50),random.randint(0,50)
                Ax,Ay = Ax*10+5, Ay*10+

        print(Ax,Ay)

        Ap=1

        return Ap,Ax,Ay
```

Ap,Ax,Ay = Apple_Spawner(Ap,Ax,Ay)

Comment: If you call the function with `Ap != 0` it returns `None`. If you want to get an helpful answer: format your code properly and add the full error trace

Comment: Please follow Python naming conventions : variable, function in lowercase ;)

Comment: Understood ! Just learnt about those

Comment: Hi, could you also show all the libraries you've imported? Would be easier on anyone trying to run your code.

Comment: gonna post the whole code then

Answer (score 0):

Your function implicitly returns None if `Ap != 0`.